# Combinations of size k

Tags: python-3.x

We have a list of numbers may be similar or not I want to generate the combination of size k I am able to do it but it is taking very much time can anyone please suggest me the better solution for this so that i can understand .
I want the fastest way to generate it. I am giving my approach also below

```
from itertools import combinations 
comb = combinations(l, k)
for i in comb:
    print(i)
```

Comment: How long is your list and how large is `k`?

Comment: list size is 100,k<=100

Comment: `binomial(100, k)` becomes very large very quickly (the maximum value is around 1e29 for `k==50`). For `5<=k<=95` the number of combinations is already > 7e7 there is no way to print all combinations in a reasonable time for k in this range.

Comment: so suggest me for 50 or 60

Comment: For `n=50`, the maximum number of combinations is still about 1.2e14. Why do you want to print all combinations anyway?

Comment: I just wanted to store them to solve a question